# Add to the path using Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

The current `add-path` command will be deprecated on November 16. I tried following their new [instructions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#adding-a-system-path) and adding the path using `echo "/path/to/dir" >> $GITHUB_PATH`, but it's not working. What is the correct command? I am building on Windows.

The error that I was seeing on github actions is `Error: The add-path command is deprecated and will be disabled on November 16th. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-github-actions-deprecating-set-env-and-add-path-commands/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, this is what worked in Windows for me

`echo "C:/Program Files (x86)/Etc" | Out-File -Append -FilePath $env:GITHUB_PATH -Encoding utf8`